# Implicit column index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Given the following MySQL table (InnoDB type):

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id`      INT     NOT NULL,
  `foo_id`  INT     NOT NULL,
  `bar_id`  INT     NOT NULL,
  `name`    VARCHAR NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  INDEX   `on_foo_id` (`foo_id`),
  INDEX   `on_bar_id` (`bar_id`),

  UNIQUE  `on_foo_bar_id` (`btl_foo_id`, `btl_bar_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note: even if I'm not using MySQL FOREIGN KEY constraints (I'm a Rails developer who handle this on the applicative level), the columns `foo_id` & `bar_id` are foreign keys.

Due to the presence of:

1. `bar_id`'s index
2. (`foo_id`, `bar_id`)'s index

...I'm wondering if the index on `foo_id` is really relevant. Maybe MySQL may already index `foo_id` even without explicitly declare this column as an index.

In other words, is it possible to remove this line:

```
INDEX   `on_foo_id` (`foo_id`),
```

without altering the performances?

Thank you for the light.

Comment: why would you think there is an implicit index on `bar_id` ? the only implicit indexes on innodb tables are `(explicit_index, id)`

Comment: @pala_: Well, given index(`foo_id, bar_id`) and index(`bar_id`), then I would imagine that there could have a kind of implicit index(`foo_id`).

Comment: `(a, b, c)` on  gives you implicit indexes on `(a, id)` and `(a,b, id)`, but not `(c)` or `(b)`. more info here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37643/are-there-implicit-indexes-in-innodb-like-myisam